# How do I force a Java Socket's InputStream to throw an IOException?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm testing a networking component I've built on top of `java.net.Socket`. I have code like this:

```
try {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]
   int bytesRead = socket.getInputStream().read(buffer);
   // more processing
} catch (IOException e) {
   handleException(e);
}
```

How can I force my `InputStream#read` call to throw an `IOException` so I can test the `handleException` method? I don't want to use mocking. I want to use the real implementation, and I want to use only Java APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

From the writing side, use an abortive close:

```
socket.setSoLinger(true, 0);
socket.close();
```

This will cause any subsequent reads from the other side to throw an `IOException`

More detail from Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/articles/connection_release.html#description):

> First, we need to distinguish the differences between an abortive and
>   an orderly connection release. To understand this distinction we need
>   to look at what happens at the TCP protocol level. It is helpful to
>   imagine an established TCP connection as actually two separate,
>   semi-independent streams of data. If the two peers are A and B, then
>   one stream delivers data from A to B, and the other stream from B to
>   A. An orderly release occurs in two stages. First one side (say A)
>   decides to stop sending data and sends a FIN message across to B. When
>   the TCP stack at B's side receives the FIN it knows that no more data
>   is coming from A, and whenever B reads all preceding data off the
>   socket, further reads will return the value -1 to indicate
>   end-of-file. This procedure is known as the TCP half-close, because
>   only one half of the connection is closed. Not surprisingly, the
>   procedure for the other half is exactly the same. B sends a FIN
>   message to A, who eventually receives a -1 after reading all preceding
>   data sent by A off the socket.
>
> By contrast, an abortive close uses the RST (Reset) message. If either
>   side issues an RST, this means the entire connection is aborted and
>   the TCP stack can throw away any queued data which has not been sent
>   or received by either application.
>
> So, how do Java applications perform orderly and abortive releases?
>   Let's consider abortive releases first. A convention that has existed
>   since the days of the original BSD sockets is that the "linger" socket
>   option can be used to force an abortive connection release. Either
>   application can call Socket.setLinger (true, 0) to tell the TCP stack
>   that when this socket is closed, the abortive (RST) procedure is to be
>   used. Setting the linger option has no immediate effect, except that
>   when Socket.close() is called subsequently, the connection is aborted
>   with an RST message. As we will see shortly, there are other ways that
>   may cause a connection to be aborted, but this is the simplest way to
>   make it happen.